# dotnet ef database update on ASP.NETCORE2.1 project with MSSQLSERVER - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification ..index 0

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

As the title says, I am trying to use dotnet ef database update from the command line and getting the error Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

From searching around this site and the internet, everything points to the connection string being wrong, but the connection string is working fine to compile and run the application. I am trying to add Identity to the project so I can have users with passwords, and am trying to follow the Deep Dive tutorial on pluralsight, but when it gets to this part, the code fails.

My connection string in appsettings.json is

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=PTI-VWS12-002;Database=EPDM_TestVault;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
},
```

The code in my Startup.cs is:

```
var migrationAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sql=> sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)));
```

though i've also tried it without the migration assembly as well. I'm really not sure what could be wrong with my connection string.

EDIT: My constructor:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } 
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) { Configuration = configuration; }
```

And my constructor has the default for ASP.NET CORE 2.1

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

EDIT 2: Solved.
I'm still not sure what I did wrong in my project, but i got the Identity tables to generate using the official Asp.NET sample project library over here https://github.com/aspnet/Docs. Using the exact migration file from the IdentityDemo, and plopping in my connection string from above, I was able to create the Identity tables in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what I did wrong in my project, but i got the Identity tables to generate using the official Asp.NET sample project library over here https://github.com/aspnet/Docs. Using the exact migration file from the IdentityDemo, and plopping in my connection string from above, I was able to create the Identity tables in my database.
EDIT: it still doesn't run in context of my program.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to configure IConfiguration using IConfigurationBuilder in Constructor of startup or in Program.cs before Kestrel Server startup.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
_configuration = builder.Build();
```

Comment: Hey. My constructor is this: 
`
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
`

Comment: Anyway, isn't that covered in the Program.cs file 

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();